# How to include synonyms filter in solr search in broadleaf ecommerce

Tags: solr, solrj, broadleaf-commerce

I'm developing an ecommerce application using broadleaf ecommerce framework. Broadleaf uses apache solr for search, I want to include synonyms filter in my schema.xml.

I follow the documentation provided by apache solr, 
First, I try to use SynonymFilterFactory by specifying

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
```

in my schema.xml of both primary, reindex cores. And placed synonyms.txt in 
\home\primary\conf and \home\reindex\conf.

When I restart my solr, I'm getting following exception
[image]

I placed this file all the places in my solr home and also in solr server still I'm getting the same error.

Also, in broadleaf I'm seeing the table BLC_SEARCH_SYNONYM, I have no idea how to use this table for synonyms. Anyone suggest a proper way to get it work in broadleaf application?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put synonyms.txt file in this path : H:\solr-8.11.1\server\solr\Employee\conf\synonyms.txt

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.